import class from NPM package with multiples class
I try to import classes from my NPM package
main.js
import { Organization, Club } from "sqorz-client";

o = new Organization();
o.setId("id");
c = new Club();
c.setId("anotherid");


I got this error :
import { Organization } from "sqorz-client";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1175:20)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:27)
at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 \

My NPM packages contains some classes,for each class i use export class ...
In index.js I import all the classes, and I use modules exports.
The code from classes is OK, my unit tests ( jest ) are OK  but if I import this in an other project it does not work.
Code from my package :
index.js
import { Organization } from "./src/types/organization";
import { Club } from "./src/types/club";
import { SqorzClient } from "./src/SqorzClient";
import { Event } from "./src/types/event";
import { Pilot } from "./src/types/pilot";
import { Race } from "./src/types/race";
import { SqorzRequest } from "./src/services/sqorzRequest";

module.exports = { Organization, Club, SqorzClient, Event, Pilot, Race, SqorzRequest };

src/types/organization.js ( result of tsc )
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Organization = void 0;
class Organization {
    getId() {
        return this._id;
    }
    setId(id) {
        this._id = id;
        return this;
    }
    getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
    setName(name) {
        this._name = name;
        return this;
    }
    getCode() {
        return this._code;
    }
    setCode(code) {
        this._code = code;
        return this;
    }
}
exports.Organization = Organization;

package.json
{
  "name": "sqorz-client",
  [...]
  "files": [
    "src"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  [...]
}

I try to

use module.exports = class in Organization.js,
change main file
change src list files
...


Does this answer your question? "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6

It looks like you're mixing CommonJS and ES Modules.

You should ensure that you have set your project up to be a module, when using import.
In your consuming app, ensure you have the following in your package.json:
{
    ... 
    "type": "module",
    ...
}


Thanks for your answer, I add type module, I got a new error :
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\dev\test-sqorz\node_modules\sqorz-client\src\types\organization' imported from D:\dev\test-sqorz\node_modules\sqorz-client\index.js
The paths are OK ..

Vscode gives me this warning
Could not find a declaration file for module 'sqorz-client'. 'd:/dev/test-sqorz/node_modules/sqorz-client/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/sqorz-client if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'sqorz-client';ts(7016)
the command does not resolve
